Mobile browser can't connect to signalR
I have been implementing an application (angular + .net core) and I am using signalR.
When I am testing the signalR with pc browsers (chrome and firefox) everything works fine. However, when I open my app with my phone, signalR does not work.
I am initializing the hub like this.
this.signalingHub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl('http://localhost:5142/signaling')
  .build();

await this.signalingHub.start().
  then(() => {//simple logic})
 .catch((error) => {//simple logic});

In catch statement, I do some tricks and I can see that this is the error message
'Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: TypeError: Failed to fetch'
I was researching this issue, and I saw one recommendation tells me this
 this.signalingHub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl('http://localhost:5142/signaling', {
     skipNegotiation: true,
     transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
   })
   .build();

I tried it and now I am getting this error
"Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled."
I was using HTTP. I wasn't sure if the problem was related to it. I started angular with SSL connection but nothing changed. I am getting same errors.

Since localhost is used, you cannot directly access localhost on your phone. You need to set a specific port to allow it. You can change it to your IP address. And in the network environment between the client and the server, ensure that the firewall is configured correctly.

yeah, that was my problem. thanks a lot!
